# Why is my ProducerBuilder class's message in .Net Core console not consumed by Kafka consumer shell?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, kafka-producer-api

I have installed Kafka on Ubuntu and managed to test a simple scenario just with shell files:

- started zookeeper with the default config
- started a node or a broker with the default config
- created a topic giving it a name, with a single partition and replication factor of 1, and associating it with the zookeeper default address
- opened a producer and a consumer:

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopicname`

followed by:

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopicname --from-beginning`

All good, everything works. Now, I want to close the producer and write the code for producer in an asp.net core application.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using Confluent.Kafka;

    namespace KafkaTraining
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var config = new ProducerConfig
                {
                    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
                };
    
                using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
                {
                    producer.Produce("mytopicname", new Message<string, string> { Value = "a log message" });
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Inspiration found here:
// https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/dotnet.html#

So, the above C# code is supposed to be equivalent with the shell command, right, plus the message I wrote in C# that should be consumed by the consumer (the consumer is still open in a terminal window thanks to a shell command).

If the shell command I posted earlier works, namely `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopicname` with just that additional info related to localhost:9092 (address of service) and topic name, why doesn't the C# program successfully substitute that, it should produce the message "a log message" and the terminal should consume it, but does not. And how could I debug this?

PS. I have installed Kafka on Linux Ubuntu from this address: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.6.0/kafka_2.12-2.6.0.tgz
whereas in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 console app, I have installed as you can see version 1.5.0, not sure if that plays a part, but no clue on how to start debugging ...
thansk for any pointers.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>KafkaDemo.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Confluent.Kafka" Version="1.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message is not being produced, because you dispose the producer before the message is delivered. `Produce` method sends a message asynchronously and doesn't wait for the response - it returns immediately. To ensure that it is sent, you can use `Flush()` - which blocks until all in-flight messages are delivered, or you can use `await ProduceAsync()`.

Try this:

```
using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
{
    producer.Produce("mytopicname", new Message<string, string> { Value = "a log message" });
    producer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Can you then add a deliveyHandler on produce method and check whether message is produced without errors?

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work with Flush, I'm so happy :-) I had used by mistake a wrong topic name. And great suggestion with the deliveryHandler, I try that next time